# How to fit logistic regression with shared measurements?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, generalized-linear-model

I have 300 individuals who rated binary responses (1 or 0) on the same set of 500 questionnaires. I want to fit a logistic regression model to explore the association between the odds of rating (1 or 0) and demographic characteristics (gender, age group, race, and education level).

Currently, I am fitting `glm()` in R

```r
glm(proportion ~ Gender + Age + Race + Education, data = data, 
    weights=rep(500, 300), family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Here, proportion = the proportion of questions where each person marked 1. For example, if an individual marked 1 for 200 questions and 0 for the remaining 300 questions, the proportion would be 0.4

For logistic regression, R's `glm()` usually takes binary variable (1 or 0) as a response variable. However, `glm()` also takes a proportion as a response variable if I specify 'weights' argument, which is the number of total trials, which is 500 (questionnaires) for everyone.

Is this the right approach? I'm concerned that there might be an issue of non-independence of observations, given that everyone is given the same set of 500 questions. The individuals are independent among each other, though.

Should I fit mixed models or anything else?

Comment: If you are using the proportion as your dependent variable (i.e with continuous values), then this is not a binary result so I don't think logistic regression is correct approach.  Have you tired standard linear regression with the `lm()` function?

Comment: @Dave2e, The glm help file says: *For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes* so the question should be fine with that.

Comment: @Grothedieck, It is not clear in the question what is being modeled.  My interpretation is to predict the proportion of answering yes, based on the IVs. If the goal is to predict whether the individual is likely to answer more yeses than no’s then I agree the proportion term is required.